# use map and cbind to summarize a list with two levels

Tags: r

I have on big list with 94 lists with the same length containing 32 elements.
Now I would like to cbind the first element of all 94 lists.

My intention was to use Map in combination with lapply.
But I do not really know how.

`Map(cbind, list1[[1]],list1[[2]],...,list1[[94]])` would give me the result but doesn't seem to be very pleasent...

Does anyone has an idea what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` with `do.call`

```
do.call(Map, c(f = cbind, lst1))
```

---

If it is to `cbind` all the first elements of the `list`

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(lst1, `[[`, 1))
```